# What is the order of $10$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm getting confused between additive and multiplicative order.
As I studied that "The order of an element of a group must divide the order of the group."  Then what is the order of $10$? Is it $16$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself how you do arithmetic in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$. $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ contains $0$, so it cannot be a multiplicative group! (There aren't multiplicative inverses). So the operation must be $+$.

As you pointed out, the order of the element must divide the order of the group. $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ has 17 elements $\{0,1,\ldots 16\}$, and 17 is prime. Therefore, 10 (and every other element of $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$) either has order 1 or order 17. The order of an element is the number of times you need to apply the group operation to get the group identity. We typically write the identity element of an additive group as $0$. $10 \bmod 17=10 \neq 0$, from which we can immediately conclude that the order of 10 is 17. We can also verify with a sanity check: $10+10+\ldots +10=10*17=170 \bmod 17 = 0$.

Comment: Actually I found this question in my paper today and I did the same solution but all of my fellows says that the order of 10 is 16 that's why I'm getting so much confused .

Comment: Applying the same logic to $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^*$ (note this is a *multiplicative* group because it does not contain 0 and hence cannot be additive), we see that 10 does have order 16 in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^*$.